# WSDL Soap Return Problem

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hey guys, how i can return SOAP Envelope or Array with all users of i selected ?
i trying to return array of database resultset, but not returning, here is my wsdl

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<definitions name="ClientSearch" targetNamespace="urn:ClientSearch" xmlns:typens="urn:ClientSearch" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
          <message name="searchUser">
                <part name="userName" type="xsd:string" />
          </message>
          <message name="searchUserResponse">
                <part name="searchUserReturn" type="xsd:string" />
          </message>
          <portType name="searchUserPortType">
                     <operation name="searchUser">
                             <input message="typens:searchUser" />
                             <output message="typens:searchUserResponse" />
                     </operation>
          </portType>
          <binding name="searchUserBinding" type="typens:searchUserPortType">
                   <operation name="searchUser">
                           <soap:operation soapAction="urn:searchUserAction" />
                           <input>
                                 <soap:body namespace="urn:ClientSearch" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
                           </input>
                           <output>
                                   <soap:body namespace="urn:ClientSearch" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                           </output>
                   </operation>
          </binding>
          <service name="clientSearchService">
                <port name="searchUserPort" binding="typens:searchUserBinding">
                        <soap:address location="http://localhost/service/server.php"/>
                </port>
        </service>
</definitions>
```

Function of i using to get data in database

```
public function searchUser( $Name ){
                      $this->__getDatabase();
                      $this->Name = (string)$Name;
                      if( !is_null( $this->Name ) ){
                           $query = $this->db->query( 'SELECT * FROM `t_users` WHERE `nome` LIKE "%'.$this->Name.'%"' );

                      }
}
```

Page of calls webserviçe

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$oSoapClient = new SOAPClient("http://localhost/service/service.wsdl");
var_dump( $oSoapClient->searchUser( 'name' ) ) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have several missing parts on your code.

1. The WSDL definition says your response is of type "string", may be you need to create a complex type to get the correct info, but as i cant see you table cant tell you the right answer
2. you are not returning anything from php function.

Correct those things and you should be fine.